Getting 2x read requests on scylla
I have a spring boot kotlin app and I am using a scylla db cluster with 3 nodes. I am using datastax java driver with LOCAL_ONE consistency and Default load balancing policy.
I am doing load testing on a get api which does 1 db call per request. When my application hits 3.2K requests per second, I can see a load of 5.4 requests per second on scylla. Although the load is balanced across all the shards, the number is approx double.
Connecting to scylla on port 9142. Also I have bypassed cache at the query level because I wanted to check how much load the db can handle. So all the requests are getting served through the db and none from cache. For referencing the screenshots, 3 instances with a prefix 10.71 are present in the cluster.




Can you please share what actual metric is used for "CQL Reads"?
